# Jade form fails to submit when separating inputs into different divs

Tags: node.js, pug

Working on prettifying a form but can't seem to figure out the error that is caused when breaking my form into different `divs`. When the form is nested inside a single `div` it submits with no problem. However, when I try to submit with the `div` heavy code, the submit button does nothing.

Here's the broken code:

```
  .container
    h5.panel-title Candidate Details
    hr
    form.form-group.input-group-sm(method='POST' action='')
    .row
      .col-sm-4
        label.form(for='name') Name
          input#name.form-control(type='text', placeholder='John Smith...' name='name' required='true' value=(undefined===candidate ? '' : candidate.name))
      .col-sm-4
        label.form(for='signed_offer_letter') Signed Offer Letter:&nbsp;
          input(type='checkbox', name='signed_offer_letter', checked=(undefined===candidate || candidate.signed_offer_letter!= true ? false:true))
    .form-group(style='padding-top:10px')
      button.btn.btn-sm(type='submit') Update  // Nothing happens on submit.
```

And if it's worth anything, here is the pre-div code that works just fine:

```
  .container
    h5.panel-title Candidate Details
    hr
    form.form-group.input-group-sm(method='POST' action='')
      label.form(for='name') Name
      input#name.form-control.input-sm(type='text', placeholder='John Smith...' name='name' required='true' value=(undefined===candidate ? '' : candidate.name))
      label.form(for='signed_offer_letter') Signed Offer Letter:&nbsp;
        input(type='checkbox', name='signed_offer_letter', checked=(undefined===candidate || candidate.signed_offer_letter!= true ? false:true))

      .form-group(style='padding-top:10px')
        button.btn.btn-sm(type='submit') Update
```

What am I missing? It seems like the `divs` should make no difference?

Comment: Can't quite tell from eyeballing, but it looks like your row and form-group divs are siblings of the form instead of children.

Comment: @DanielSchaffer That did it. Seems obvious now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indention is not right. The form and the div are sibling whereas div should be a child of form.

```
.container
    h5.panel-title Candidate Details
    hr
    form.form-group.input-group-sm(method='POST' action='')
        .row
          .col-sm-4
            label.form(for='name') Name
              input#name.form-control(type='text', placeholder='John Smith...' name='name' required='true' value=(undefined===candidate ? '' : candidate.name))
          .col-sm-4
            label.form(for='signed_offer_letter') Signed Offer Letter:&nbsp;
              input(type='checkbox', name='signed_offer_letter', checked=(undefined===candidate || candidate.signed_offer_letter!= true ? false:true))
        .form-group(style='padding-top:10px')
          button.btn.btn-sm(type='submit') Update  // Nothing happens on submit.
```